# How to use cq:editConfig Property in AEM 6.0

Tags: aem

In AEM 6.0, I am having a component and, it has a text field and one video file uploader. I want to enable the drag and drop of this video from the content finder. My normal upload using the dialog is working, but this drag and drop is not working. I searched and found out that I can do this by using cq:editConfig. Can somebidy tell me that how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the `cq:dropTargets`, as a child of the `cq:editConfig` node to configure the list of drop targets that can accept a drop from an asset of the content finder.

In your case, for a video, you can refer the `foundation/components/video` whose edit config is shown below.

```
<cq:editConfig jcr:primaryType="cq:EditConfig" cq:layout="editbar">
    <cq:dropTargets jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
        <video jcr:primaryType="cq:DropTargetConfig" propertyName="./asset">
            <parameters jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured" 
                sling:resourceType="foundation/components/video"/>
        </video>
    </cq:dropTargets>
</cq:editConfig>
```

Also make sure you specify the `ddGroups` and `ddAccept` properties on the `html5smartfile` widget used for video file upload component.

Refer [Configuring the Edit Behaviour of a component](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-1/develop/components.html#Configuring%20the%20Edit%20Behaviour%20of%20a%20Component) to get more insights on configuring the edit config and its child nodes.

Comment: can you also tell that from where you get this xml representation of the cq properties. I am still working with the CRXDe structure.

Comment: You can get the XML representation of any node using the `.xml` extension of the node path i.e., `http://localhost:4502/libs/foundation/components/video/cq:editConfig.xml` would give you the above XML. Similary you can use the `.json` extension to get the JSON representation of the same. However, JSON representation would only contain the current node properties and not the entire child, in that case use `infinity` selector along with `json` extension. i.e.,  `http://localhost:4502/libs/foundation/components/video/cq:editConfig.infinity.json`

Answer (score 0):

You must be careful doing this because it can have an unexpected side effect of changing your component type to the type specified in the drop target.

To avoid that happening, you can distinguish between component type and target type by using this format:

```
<cq:dropTargets jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
    <video
        jcr:primaryType="cq:DropTargetConfig"
        accept="[video/.*]"
        propertyName="./asset">
        <parameters
            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
            sling:resourceType="myfolder/components/videoandtext">
            <video
                jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                sling:resourceType="foundation/components/video"
                />
        </parameters>
    </video>
</cq:dropTargets>
```

See here for more info: [Drop Target Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17812201/drop-target-issue)